# How does the last part of this Python code do what it does?

Tags: python, truncate

Essential what this code does is it takes a .txt file, replaces "    " with "|"
then after it replaces it, it then goes back in and deletes any rows that start with a "|"

Im having trouble understanding what the last part of this code does.

**I understand everything up until the:**

```
output = [line for line in txt if not line.startswith("|")]
f.seek(0)
f.write("".join(output))
f.truncate()
```

everything before this code ^^ i understand but im not sure how this code does what its doing.

--------this is the full code----------

```
# This imports the correct package
import datetime

# this creates "today" as the variable that holds todays date
today = datetime.date.today().strftime("%Y%m%d")

# Read the file
with open(r'\\mlgserver04\mlgshare\DataTransfer&AuditCompliance\ARSI Calls\CallLog_ARSI_' + today + '.txt', 'r') as file:
   filedata = file.read()

# Replace the target string
filedata = filedata.replace('   ', '|')

# Write the file out again
with open(r'\\mlgserver04\mlgshare\DataTransfer&AuditCompliance\ARSI Calls\CallLog_ARSI_' + today + '.txt', 'w') as file:
   file.write(filedata)

# opens the file
with open(r'\\mlgserver04\mlgshare\DataTransfer&AuditCompliance\ARSI Calls\CallLog_ARSI_' + today + '.txt','r+') as f:
    txt = f.readlines()
    output = [line for line in txt if not line.startswith("|")]
    f.seek(0)
    f.write("".join(output))
    f.truncate()
```

Answer (score 1):

f.read() returns a blob of data (string or bytes)
On the other hand, f.readlines() returns a LIST of strings or bytes.

```
output = [line for line in txt if not line.startswith("|")]
```

This is the same thing as saying

```
output = []
for line in txt:
  if not line.startswith("|"):
    output.append(line)
```

So, make a NEW list of strings, consisting of only the ones that we want to keep.

```
"".join(output)
```

Join takes an iterable of strings, and adds them together with the delimiter (in this case, it was ""). so output[0] + "" + output[1] and so on.

Finally, write that final string back to the file.

Comment: i was having such a HARD time understaning the for loop written in that way, but now that you described it, its a lot easier to read

Comment: im still having a bit of trouble understanding the "JOIN" code, any source you may find where i can read up on it and understand the logic/theory behind it to better understand your answer?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join. It may be easier if you understand that `", ".join(["first", "second", "last"])` returns `"first, second, last"`